# About the word 'finite'

Tags: meaning

> Everything is transient and finite, existing in the medium of time

1. What's the *finite* thing?
2. Do you agree with it?

Comment: I think the second question is offtopic for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. something that is finite is something that has ends or limits, it's opposite is perhaps a slightly more common word, infinite, meaning without limits or ends, everlasting etc.
2. probably, certianly most things do have a finite lifetime, but it's a rather philosphical statement so either view could probably be supported. e.g. if everything in the medium of time ends what about time itself?

Comment: Time _is_ the medium, not within it. :)

Comment: which would be a way out of that specific one, but what about the vaccuum does that end? what about the universe does that end given you may not have a concept of time if it does? and you could bring metaphysics into it and come up with pretty much any answer you like

Answer (score 0):

Finite = having bounds or limits, not infinite, [in maths] not zero.

Do I agree? Yes, because infinite is a logical concept that cannot be proved. As much as something might appear infinite, it's bounds may simply be beyond the range of your vision or comprehension.

Describing finite as not infinite is curious, but it comes about because the concept of infinity came first (from the latin word finitus), whereas finite came sometime later (15C so I've read)

Comment: Not Zero #1: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/finite

Comment: Note Zero #2: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/finite

Comment: 'Finite' means 'Not Infinite', That means that if something is 'not infinite', it must logically be 'finite'. Perhaps, there is a word to describe something that in neither finite or infinite... but if there is, I am unaware of it.

Comment: "infinite is a logical concept that cannot be proved" is, logically, meaningless. As are statements like "result of any product of zero is 'undefined'" (?) and "zero is also infinite because it also has no bounds". I have no idea what you mean by any of them, because under the natural mathematical meanings, they are all false statements.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - You are right... I'm in danger of tying myself in knots trying to explain something that it is several levels beyond my ability simply to reinforce an entirely different point - I'll remove it.

Comment: @CJM: "That means that if something is 'not infinite', it must logically be 'finite'": this is a philosophical (or logical) position which is reasonable, but not necessarily true. In mathematics there are (provably) undecideables, i.e. statements which in any given logical framework, neither P nor ~P is proveably true.

Comment: @Colin: If something is not infinite, it is finite, and vice-versa. This is true commonsensically, logically, and mathematically. On the other hand, if you cannot *show* that something is infinite, it does not mean that it is finite (maybe you just failed at proving, and maybe it's impossible to prove), which is what Jasper said and probably what you were getting at. 

[BTW, you interchanged the quantifiers in Gödel's theorem: it should say "in any given logical framework there are statements which…" etc., not "there are statements which in any given logical framework…" etc. :-)]

Comment: @CJM: Last comments for the day: (1) in mathematics, zero *is* finite (and bounded); the dictionary is wrong about the mathematical meaning, and (2) you *can* prove that certain things are infinite (e.g. the famous proof that the number of primes is infinite), and you can obviously prove that certain things are finite (e.g., the number 5 is finite), so "infinite is a logical concept that cannot be proved" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Determined to flog a dead horse, eh? You might be right about the maths, but forgive me if I take the word of a couple of on-line dictionaries over your comments. Just hedging my bets. Secondly, the quote makes sense, even if you don't agree with it. Finally, does any of this help the OP?

Comment: @CJM: Well, it's not a dead horse yet, because the vague statement is still in the answer to confuse/mislead the OP and anyone who may read it later. :-) You make it seem as if infinity is something fuzzy and undefined, when in fact it has several precise definitions. And I still don't understand what "infinite is a logical concept that cannot be proved" can possibly mean. You can prove statements, but what does it mean to prove a concept? If you mean that "you cannot prove about anything that it is infinite", then it's false (I already gave an example)… so you must mean something else: what?